# How to Make Linux Partition Bootable?

Tags: linux, bootable-media

I need help. I've ended up on my Linux machine without a bootable drive. I need to make one of my drives bootable.

Any ideas?

Comment: 1) I'm not an expert, but is it actually necessary? I, for one, don't see partitions with this flag set on my system. 2) I think the flag can be set with `fdisk`, but I'm not sure you can retain the data when toggling the flag. 3) This question is more likely to be answered at unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the flag with fdisk or parted. But you have to read the manual pages yourself! :)

Do man parted or man fdisk.

In addition, you need to have a boot manager (such as Grub) installed and configured.

Comment: Only giving the boot flag is not enough, you need to know what type of bootloader is used,